# How do I do a bitwise Not operation in Python?

Tags: python

In order to test building an Xor operation with more basic building blocks (using Nand, Or, and And in my case) I need to be able to do a Not operation. The built-in `not` only seems to do this with single bits. If I do:

```
x = 0b1100
x = not x
```

I should get `0b0011` but instead I just get `0b0`. What am I doing wrong? Or is Python just missing this basic functionality?

I know that Python has a built-in Xor function but I've been using Python to test things for an HDL project/course where I need to build an Xor gate. I wanted to test this in Python but I can't without an equivalent to a Not gate.

Comment: You need to watch out. not is not a bitwise operator. These are bit wise operators (they actually map to gates): https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Comment: In fact you are not getting `0b0` but the `False` singleton, since `not` always returns the opposite of the truthiness of its operand, no matter what that is.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The problem with using `~` in Python, is that it works with signed integers. This is also the only way that really makes sense unless you limit yourself to a particular number of bits. It *will* work ok with bitwise math, but it can make it hard to interpret the intermediate results.

For 4 bit logic, you should just subtract from `0b1111`

```
0b1111 - 0b1100  # == 0b0011
```

For 8 bit logic, subtract from `0b11111111` etc.

The general form is

```
def bit_not(n, numbits=8):
    return (1 << numbits) - 1 - n
```

Comment: Thanks! It would be nice if Python allowed unsigned numbers, but that would be a huge change, so this works. :)

Comment: Note that you can also phrase this as constructing a mask and ANDing with it (Python's pseudo-two's complement system handles that properly by reducing to a positive number constrained by the mask), e.g. `return ~n & ((1 << numbits) - 1)`. You solution works fine, but feels sort of backwards to me, simply because I prefer to think in terms of actually flipping the bits, then masking to the proper width.

Comment: John's method's faster though

Comment: I don't see why the python Mighty Ones don't add 'xor' to the 'operator' module.

We have bitwise 'and' and 'or, so why not 'xor' and 'not'?

Answer (score 12):

Another way to achieve this, is to assign a mask like this (should be all 1's):

```
mask = 0b1111
```

Then xor it with your number like this:

```
number = 0b1100
mask = 0b1111
print(bin(number ^ mask))
```

You can refer the xor truth table to know why it works.

Comment: For the record, this relies on the input already falling in that range, or the output will remain outside the range; you can't use it for cutdown. If you want it to work for numbers that might exceed the desired range, `~number & mask` works with only slightly more work, and looks closer to the logic of what you intend. e.g. `0x12345 ^ 0xffff` gets `0x1dcba`, while `~0x12345 & 0xffff` gets `0xdcba`.

Answer (score 11):

Python bitwise `~` operator invert all bits of integer but we can't see native result because all integers in Python has signed representation.

Indirectly we can examine that:

```
>>> a = 65
>>> a ^ ~a
-1
```

Or the same:

```
>>> a + ~a
-1
```

Ther result -1 means all bits are set. But the minus sign ahead don't allow us to directly examine this fact:

```
>>> bin(-1)
'-0b1'
```

The solution is simple: we must use unsigned integers.
First way is to import `numpy` or `ctypes` modules wich both support unsigned integers. But numpy more simplest using than ctypes (at least for me):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.uint8(0b1100)
y = ~x
```

Check result:

```
>>> bin(x)
'0b1100'
>>> bin(y)
'0b11110011'
```

And finally check:

```
>>> x + y
255
```

Unsigned integer '255' for 8-bits integers (bytes) mean the same as '-1' becouse has all bits set to 1. Make sure:

```
>>> np.uint8(-1)
255
```

---

And another simplest solution, not quite right, but if you want to include additional modules, you can invert all bits with XOR operation, where second argument has all bits are set to 1:

```
a = 0b1100
b = a ^ 0xFF
```

This operation will also drop most significant bit of signed integer and we can see result like this:

```
>>> print('{:>08b}'.format(a))
00001100
>>> print('{:>08b}'.format(b))
11110011
```

---

Finally solution contains one more operation and therefore is not optimal:

```
>>> b = ~a & 0xFF
>>> print('{:>08b}'.format(b))
11110011
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's called the bitwise complement [operator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators):

```
~0b1100
```

Comment: this answer is wrong; because python integers are signed, `~i` is always trivially `-i-1` for any integer `i`

Comment: Well, that's usually what you expect when you're doing bit-wise operations on an integer, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The answers here collectively have great nuggets in each one, but all do not scale well with depending on edge cases.

Rather than fix upon an 8-bit mask or requiring the programmer to change how many bits are in the mask, simply create a mask based on input via [`bit_length()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length):

```py
def bit_not(num):
    return num ^ ((1 << num.bit_length()) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

string of binary can be used to preserve the left 0s, since we know that:

```
bin(0b000101) # '0b101'
bin(0b101)    # '0b101'
```

This function will return string format of the NOT of input number

```
def not_bitwise(n):
     ''' 
     n: input string of binary number (positive or negative)
     return: binary number (string format)
     '''
     head, tail = n.split('b')
     not_bin = head+'b'+tail.replace('0','a').replace('1','0').replace('a','1')
     return not_bin
```

Example:

```
In[266]: not_bitwise('0b0001101')
Out[266]: '0b1110010'

In[267]: int(not_bitwise('0b0001101'), 2)

Out[267]: 114

In[268]: not_bitwise('-0b1010101')

Out[268]: '-0b0101010'

In[269]: int(not_bitwise('-0b1010101'), 2)
Out[269]: -42
```

Answer (score -1):

The general form given by John La Rooy, can be simplified in this way (python == 2.7 and >=3.1):

```
def bit_not(n):
    return (1 << n.bit_length()) - 1 - n
```

Comment: This only works if `n`'s logical high bit is set to `1`. If you're logically working with eight bit numbers, then this will work for `n in range(128, 256)`, but for `n in range(128)`, it will fail to set the high bits. This also makes it non-reversible (because the number will continually shrink on each reversal as the high bits that should have been preserved are lost); even when the high bit is set, the result won't have it set, so the next reversal becomes wrong.