# Bitwise not, can somebody explain this example?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, xor

Can somebody explain this example through binary digits?

```
>>> ~11
-12
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31151236/8881141

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 8 bit representation (you can use larger representations for the same results):

```
~11 => ~ b 00001011
```

Applying NOT operator yields (1 turns to 0 and vice versa):

```
~(b 00001011) => b 11110100
```

The result is negative (since the left most bit is the sign bit). To discover its value, apply 2's complement operator (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)):

```
b 11110100, negate bits:
b 00001011, add 1:
+        1
----------
b 00001100 => 12
```

Meaning that the result was -12.

Comment: May I asked, why -1? I believe the explanation is totally correct, will be happy to discuss if anyone thinks otherwise

Answer (score 0):

```
def toBinary(n):
    return ''.join(str(1 & int(n) >> i) for i in range(64)[::-1])
```

toBinary(11) Returns

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001011
```

toBinary(-12) Returns

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110100
```

From Python Docs
~x : Returns the complement of x - the number you get by switching each 1 for a 0 and each 0 for a 1. This is the same as -x - 1. 
For More : https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators