# Getting errors for negative numbers when manipulating binary data from a file. What's the most appropriate way to handle this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-data

I have some c++ code that manipulates binary data for a proprietary storage system.  As part of it, I have this code from c++ (variable names changed for clarity):

```
void get_data(unsigned char* data) {
    data[0] = (~data[0] ^ 0x55);
```

Where `data` was read straight from a binary file.

This logic was handled by not changing anything and python's use of bitwise operators mean that I can just straight up copy the code.

```
data = bytearray(fd.read(2048))
data[0] = (~data[0] ^ 0x55)
```

And the exception is `ValueError: byte must be in range(0, 256)`.  This is because the first byte value `34` gets the twos complement of `-35`.

I'm not sure of the proper way to handle this.  In c++, a char has ONLY 0-255.  Python does not have that, so do I somehow handle it like an unsigned int or is there a more appropriate way to handle it?

One idea was to take every byte and:

```
byte_value = byte_value & 0xff
```

Another person suggested I use the `ctypes.c_ubyte` type.  Then I remembered two things I'd experimented with in the past.  `struct` to pull the numbers out and store them properly or the `bitstring` module to read and manipulate the data that way.

Is there a proper way to handle this, either for being 'pythonic' or for having better performance?

Comment: Related reading: [How do I do a bitwise Not operation in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31151107/953482). The "subtract from 0b11111111" suggestion in the top answer should give you values in 0-255 as desired.

Comment: Ohhhh...  so `~` is not the same as the `not` operator.  I did not know that!

Comment: In that case, is it better to use `0b11111111 - <number>`?  Do I lose or gain a performance hit if I just do a numeric subtraction of `255 - <number>`?

Comment: `0b11111111 - <number>` and `255 - <number>` produce identical bytecode, so they should have the same performance. Personally, I'm curious whether `255 - <number>` is faster than `<number> ^ 255`...