# CRC - Python - How to calculate JAMCRC decimal number from string

Tags: python, decimal, crc, crc32

I need to calculate CRC-32/JAMCRC decimal number from a string in Python 3.
How can I do it?
For example, this webpage does it: https://www.crccalc.com/ - for 'hello-world' it prints 1311505828.
I would like to have script which does exactly the same calculation.
I've already tried to use zlib.crc32 and binascii.crc32 but their results for 'hello-world' is 2983461467.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compute the CRC-32/JAMCRC you can simply perform the bitwise-not of the standard CRC-32 (in your case, the CRC-32 of 'hello-world' is 2983461467). But you can't simply use the `~` operator, because it works with signed integers (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31151236)). Instead, you first need a subtraction:

```
import zlib
x = b'hello-world'
crc32_jamcrc = int("0b"+"1"*32, 2) - zlib.crc32(x) # 1311505828
```

Comment: Is it possible to calculate JAMCRC without converting the string to bytes?