# Inverting bits in python

Tags: python, binary, bit-manipulation

I am doing some calculations and I was wondering how you can invert a byte in python.

For example:

`0b11111111` should be flipped to `0b00000000`.

I have tried turning into a string and flipping it then but I cant somehow turn it back into a Integer.

Also, I want to add that the ~ does not work, as it simply just makes the same number but negative

Comment: Look at the `^`  operator. `^ 0b11111111`

Comment: @trincot already tried that. It Simply shows as syntax error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I do a bitwise Not operation in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31151107/how-do-i-do-a-bitwise-not-operation-in-python)

Comment: Syntax error? Did you look at the documentation? for instance: `0b10101 ^ 0b11111111 == 0b11101010`

Comment: @trincot Okay I got!
 `a = 0b11111111^0b00101010

print(bin(a))`
This gives me The opposite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 bin(0b11010111 ^ 0b11111111) // bit subtraction
 # Result
 # bin(0b11010111 ^ 0b11111111)
 #'0b101000'
 # for each bit subtraction with 1 occur
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation of your solution?

Comment: I added comments to solution

Answer (score 1):

To explain why `~` *"dit not work"*: you want to invert all bits in a byte (8-bits), but the `0b....` value is not a byte, but an int which has more bits than just 8.
`~var` inverts all bits in an integer. You can clear all bits except the lowest 8 with a mask to get the result you expect:

```
MASK8 = 0b11111111  # or 255 decimal

v = 0b11101110                                                                                                                                                    
inv = ~v & MASK8    # 0b10001
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def flippingBits(n):
    binary_list=list(bin(n))[2::]
    binary_32=''
    binary_result=''
    for item in binary_list:
        if item=='1':
            binary_32+='0'
        else:
            binary_32+='1'
    if 32-len(binary_list)>0:
        for i in range(32-len(binary_list)):
            binary_result+='1'
        binary_result+=binary_32
    else:
        binary_result=binary_32
    result=int(binary_result, 2)
    return result
```

This is a solution a made for a flipping bits in hacker rank:
The function receive an unsigned int, turn this number into a binary representation and flip all the bits in a 32 bits representation, then return the unsigned int number corresponding to the remaining binary number.
First I change into the binary representation using the bin() function, then i tansform that into a string with a for loop but changing every bit for the opposite(flipping), last I concatenate the string with the difference between the string length and the 32 spaces I need (32 bits), adding 1s to the rest of the string. Last I change into an integer using int(number, base) function.
I hope it helps you.