# How does Python infer the number of bits to use in a binary NOT?

Tags: python, binary, integer, bit-manipulation

I'm translating this from C to Python:

```c
int_fast16_t x;
int_fast16_t y = compute_value();
x = ~y;
y = x+1;
```

I don't think

```
y = compute_value()
y = (~y) + 1
```

will work: how would it know on how many bits should the binary NOT be done? (8? 16? 32?).

In the case of C, it is explicit with the type `int_fast16_t`, but with Python we don't know a number of bits in advance.

How do you do this in Python?

I have read [How do I do a bitwise Not operation in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31151107/how-do-i-do-a-bitwise-not-operation-in-python) but here it's more specific: **how does Python infer the number of bits to use in a binary NOT?**

Example:

How does Python know if the binary NOT of `3` (`0b11`) should be done on 4 bits: `0b00` or on 8 bits: `0b11111100` or on 16 bits: `0b1111111111111100`?

Comment: This should work fine, though you can `& 0xffff` the result to clamp it if you want to be safe.  Also, those two steps are equivalent to `x=-x` since python always uses 2's complement.

Comment: @dbush Thanks, but how does Python know if binary NOT of 3 (`0b11`) should be done on 4 bits: `0b00` or on 8 bits: `0b11111100` or on 16 bits: `0b1111111111111100`?

Comment: @Basj Just as positive numbers implicitly have an infinite number of high-order zero bits, negative numbers implicitly have an infinite number of high-order 1 bits.

Comment: @Barmar This is a good visual way to understand this! You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Python `int` has an infinite number of bits. The only way to invert them all is to negate the sign of the number.  So for example `~1` is `-2`. To get a specific number of bits in the result, you have to mask off those bits.  `(~1)&0xffff` is `0xfffe` which is one bit off, I assume due to two's complement.

Comment: could you also use `.bit_length()` to get the number of bits? for example: `a=1; (~a).bit_length()`

Comment: @jakub That still requires Python to calculate `~a` first, so it needs to determine how many bits it requires.

Comment: @Barmar it just inverts all the bits it has stored and doesn't worry about the rest, I assume. I haven't checked the source to see what it actually does, if someone else did that would make an even better answer.

Comment: if it helps, here is the [code for inverting and integer](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/eb618d5ff0371efead28a3afa91834e4beebf73d/Objects/longobject.c#L4615-L4629) and the [code for `int.bit_length()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/854db1a6061c83d80a3f1e4e87f043b521719920/Objects/longobject.c#L5624-L5686)

Answer (score 1):

> how does Python infer the number of bits to use in a binary NOT?

It uses *all* bits in the binary representation it has for the operand. Python integers consist of one or more `long`s (see [Python integer objects](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html)).

> How does Python know if the binary NOT of 3 (0b11) should be done on 4 bits: 0b00 or on 8 bits: 0b11111100 or on 16 bits: 0b1111111111111100?

There is no case where it would be just 4 or 8 bits. It is done on *all* bits in the 64 bits it has for the integer (or a multiple of that, if the original value needed more long words).